# How to mirror and fade the stretched content of a div? (anything better than -webkit-box-reflect?)

Tags: html, css

There are numerous examples of mirroring but in this case, mirroring a stretched image inside a div container does not work with the usual `:after { background: inherit; transform: scaleY(-1); }`

This is my base:

```css
.container {
    background-color: orange; // for debugging
    max-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
 }
 .container img {width: 100%; height: 139px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <image src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4cm.jpg"/>
</div>
```

But trying to mirror the content of div fails:

```css
.container2 {
    position: relative;
    // background: url(217_5_grayscalereversed.png) bottom;
    // can't be used because I'm stretching horizontally the image
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 139px;
    margin: 10px;
}
  .container2 img {width: 100%; height: 139px;}

  .container2:after,
  .container2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: -52%;
}
.container2:after {
  background: inherit;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.container2:before {
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), #fff);
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
    <image src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4cm.jpg"/>
</div>
```

The image (wxh: 17073x139 pixels):

[image: image to mirror]

**1. How should I mirror the stretched content of this div ?**

With another attempt, using `-webkit-box-reflect`, I have a good result (bottom with Edge) except with few browsers (firefox, top):

[image: attempt2]

```css
.container {
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 10px;
 }
 .container img {width: 100%; height: 139px;}
.overlap {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
.ball { animation: an 4s 4s 3 alternate ease-in-out forwards;}
@keyframes an {
    0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
    50% { transform: translateX(50px); }
    100% { transform: translateX(100px); }
}
.bag {background-color: aliceblue; padding: 5px;}
.original {
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 0px linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
.reflection {
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bag">
    <div class="container original">
        <image src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4cm.jpg" />
        <svg viewbox="0 0 200 70" width="100vw" height="139px" class="overlap">
            <line class="ball" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="139" style="stroke:rgba(223, 0, 0, 0.993);stroke-width:1" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="reflection"></div>
</div>
```

**2. What alternative with better browser support do I have to achieve a similar result ?**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but i'm not sure on what you want to do.
If you just want to make an axial symmetry along the horizontal axis, you should just use `scaleY(-1)` on the second `div`...

I saw you put pseudo elements `before` / `after` but I don't understand the purpose.

Try to be more precise, or give us an image (photoshoped) of the desired result and i'll edit my answer, if I can :D

### UPDATED:

I updated the snippet to be closer to your needs.
I managed to create something similar to your version without the need of `-webkit-box-reflect`.
I tested it on chrome, firefox and safari, all good.

I tried to keep the most basic html (no svg or extra element needed)
The code could be tricky, I tried to explain the CSS...
You still need to put the image source in the CSS to create the "reflect"

In brief :

- `.container` is extendend with two peusdo classes
- `::before` is the red animated cursor
- `::after` is the reflect
- *cursor* overlaps both the image and the reflection and the color is a `linear-gradient`.

Even if this works (I hope so), it is way too complex than the standard `-webkit-box-reflect` ;-D

Hope it helps.

```css
/* not usefull for your needs, I just wanted to display it correctly for tests in codepen */ 
.bag { 
  background-color: olive
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  position: relative; /* to allow overlaping */
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 10px;
  display: flex;      /* to join properly both the image and the reflect */
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 139px;
}
 
/* the moving "cursor" */
.container::before {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 2;
  top: calc(139px - 75px); /* center verticaly between "images" */
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 150px;
  width: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0px, red 50%, transparent 100%);
  animation: an 4s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out forwards;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* the reflect */
.container::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 139px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255, .2) 0%, white 100%), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4cm.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 100% 139px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

@keyframes an {
    0% { left: 0; }
    50% { left:50%; }
    100% { left: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="bag">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4cm.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

See the Pen 
  [stackoverflow.com/posts#71199399](https://codepen.io/optyler/pen/bGYMbGx) by P. Ferreira ([@optyler](https://codepen.io/optyler))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: I added an example using the same principles. The problem with your code is that your repeating the source of the image and that's not the reflection, it's another div with etc.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, i'll try to give you an update ;)

Comment: Very interesting. Did you try to keep the svg cursor? If not why? The idea is to move it with js as the music is played.

Comment: I removed the `svg` because I thought you'd like your html as clean as possible and don't know the purpose of the "cursor". 
You can obviously keep the svg image, but you have to do the same trick I used = add opacity on the bottom side of the cursor cut in half :p

Comment: By the way, I think you can safely get all the css in the `::before` section, create a class (`.cursor`) with it and add a `<div class=cursor></div>` element as the first element of the `.container`. 
You then should be able to "move" the cursor with JS specifying directly on the `div` the left property.

Answer (score 0):

use `transform: scaleY(-1);` on the img

```css
.container {
    background-color: orange; // for debugging
    max-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
 }
 .container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 139px;
    transform:scaleY(-1);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4cm.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You flipped the image, this is not a reflection of div with the fading.